# unmarshalling xml arrays of mixed object types

Tags: xml, go, polymorphism, unmarshalling

I am processing received XML which contains an unordered list of messages where each message can be of one of several distinct types. Order isn't significant.

I have worked out a way to do what I want (after much struggle, this is day 3 of learning go) but am hung up on how to robustly deal with unexpected message types

Here's some code

```golang
package main

import (
  "encoding/xml"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {

  data := `<Envelope>
             <Body>
               <Response>
                 <Messages>
                   <Greeting>
                     <From>Fred</From>
                   </Greeting>
                   <Reminder>
                     <Time>12</Time>
                     <Subject>Lunch at Joe's</Subject>
                   </Reminder>
                   <NewThing>Report me!</NewThing>
                   <Reminder>
                     <Time>6</Time>
                     <Subject>Catch the train</Subject>
                   </Reminder>
                   <Greeting>
                     <From>Mary</From>
                     <Extra>Hi</Extra>
                   </Greeting>
                 </Messages>
                 <MessageCount>3</MessageCount>
               </Response>
             </Body>
           </Envelope>`

  type Greeting struct {
    From string 
  }

  type Reminder struct {
    Time int
    Subject string
  }

  type TopLevel struct {
    Messages struct {
      GreetingList []Greeting `xml:"Greeting"`
      ReminderList []Reminder `xml:"Reminder"`
    } `xml:"Body>Response>Messages"`
  }

  var reply TopLevel

  err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &reply) 
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  for _, reminder := range reply.Messages.ReminderList {
    fmt.Printf("Reminder: '%s' at %d\n", reminder.Subject, reminder.Time)
  }

  for _, greeting := range reply.Messages.GreetingList {
    fmt.Printf("Greetings From: %s\n", greeting.From)
  }

}
```

The output is

```
Reminder: 'Lunch at Joe's' at 12
Reminder: 'Catch the train' at 6
Greetings From: Fred
Greetings From: Mary
```

I would also like to be able to find unexpected types of message that are neither `<Greeting>` nor `<Reminder>`, such as the `<NewThing>` without knowing anything about new things (etc) in advance.

```
Warning: Unexpected message type: NewThing.
```

Should I be thinking of some way to have a single list of generic objects? Or using structs of XMLname + innerxml strings somehow? Not sure how to process a single list of such dissimilar types.

Clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle unexpected XML elements using the `, any` and `, innerxml` tags.

code changes are ([run full example at go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rTNDGlj89K))

```golang
  type Any struct {
    XMLName xml.Name 
    Content string   `xml:",innerxml"`
  }

  type TopLevel struct {
    Messages struct {
      GreetingList   []Greeting `xml:"Greeting"`
      ReminderList   []Reminder `xml:"Reminder"`
      UnexpectedList []Any      `xml:",any"`
    } `xml:"Body>Response>Messages"`
  }

  ...

  for _, unexpected := range reply.Messages.UnexpectedList {
    fmt.Printf("Unexpected: %s containing '%s'\n", unexpected.XMLName, unexpected.Content)
  }
```

output

```
Reminder: 'Lunch at Joe's' at 12
Reminder: 'Catch the train' at 6
Greetings From: Fred
Greetings From: Mary
Unexpected: { NewThing} containing 'Report me!'
Unexpected: { NewerThing} containing '<Fruit>Apple</Fruit><Sales>42</Sales>'
```